# Managing web.config appSettings

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I wanted a pattern to manage web.config appsettings. I want to be able to have a default setting if the config setting was missing. I also wanted the check for the value in the config file to happen only once, not each time the the value is retrieved.

```
Public NotInheritable Class ExternalReportRequestBL

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The default value for max number of request attempts
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Shared _ReportRequestMaxExecuteAttemptDefault As Integer

    Shared Sub New()
        If Not Integer.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ReportRequestMaxExecuteAttempt"), ExternalReportRequestBL._ReportRequestMaxExecuteAttemptDefault) Then
            _ReportRequestMaxExecuteAttemptDefault = 10
        End If
    End Sub

    Friend Shared ReadOnly Property MaxNumberOfTries As Integer
        Get
            Return ExternalReportRequestBL._ReportRequestMaxExecuteAttemptDefault
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Now, I can access the variable from anywhere in the assembly:

```
ExternalReportRequestBL.MaxNumberOfTries
```

What are your thoughts?

Comment: May I ask what lend you to wanting this? Typically, those settings are specifically for specifying defaults and configuration settings. I'm smelling an XY problem, but I don't yet understand what your real problem is.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.TryParse` will overwrite the value of that shared property with 0 if the value is not there. Use something like this instead:

```
Shared Sub New()
    Dim parsed As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ReportRequestMaxExecuteAttempt"), parsed) Then
        _ReportRequestMaxExecuteAttemptDefault = parsed
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are correct. Changed my question accordingly.